# Error : Type String is not assignable to type '{ name : string; }' in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to define a scope variable in Angular 2. Here is the code:

```
export class GroceryComponent {
  task = {
    name: ''
  };
  tasks = [];
}
```

But its throwing the following error :

```
Type String is not assignable to type '{ name : string; }'
```

Comment: Where is it throwing that error? Where are you using `task`? So many questions

Answer (score 2):

Probably other parts of your code try to **change** the `task` property from the `instance` of `GroceryComponent`

Something similar with this error:

```
class GroceryComponent {
  task = {
    name : ""
  };
  tasks = [];
};

let product  = new GroceryComponent();
product.task = 55; // ERROR MESSAGE: Type '55' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }'.
```

Interactive example on: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20GroceryComponent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20task%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%20%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20tasks%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20product%20%20%3D%20new%20GroceryComponent()%3B%0D%0Aproduct.task%20%3D%2055%3B)

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? I am on `1.0.0-beta.20-4` version. It's working for me.

But anyway you can also put that into a type alias:

```
export class GroceryComponent {
    task = {
        name: '' as string, name1: '' as string
    };
    tasks = [];
}
```